# Determine value of $\alpha$ given probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, exponential-function

> Suppose that $X$ is a random variable satisfying that, for some $\alpha > 0$,

> $\mathbb{P}(X=k)=e^{-2}\frac{2^{k-2}}{k!}(1+\alpha k),$ $k=\{0,1,2,...\}$.
> Determine the value of $\alpha$

No further information are given, I proceed in equating

$\sum^\infty_{k=0} p_X(k):=\sum^\infty_{k=0}\mathbb{P}(X=k)=\sum^\infty_{k=0}e^{-2}\frac{2^{k-2}}{k!}(1+\alpha k)=1 $ $\Rightarrow \sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{2^{k}}{k!}(1+\alpha k)=4e^2$

Further I know the Taylor expansion of $e^x$, so I have:

$4e^2=4\sum^\infty_{k=0}\frac{2^{k}}{k!}$

Something appears wrong to me, moreover the last term in the sum with $\alpha$ depends on $k$ and I cannot take it out, how can I proceed?

Comment: Does that formula for $\mathbb{P}(X = k)$ look somewhat familiar at all... i.e., a special name?

Answer (score 1):

Distribute out the sum:
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!}(1+\alpha k) 
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!} + \alpha\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!}
\cdot k \\
&= e^2 + \alpha\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!}
\cdot k \\
&= e^2 + 2\alpha\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} \\
&= e^2 + 2\alpha\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^{k}}{k!} \\
&= e^2 + 2e^2\alpha
\end{align*}
$$
Since you've found that this expression is also equal to $4e^2$, you can now solve for $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Lets do some calculations

$$\mathbb{P}(X = k ) = e^{-2}\frac{2^{k-2}}{k!}(1+\alpha k) = e^{-2}\frac{2^{k}}{k!}\frac{1+\alpha k} {2^2} $$

$\implies$

$$4e^2 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!}(1+\alpha k) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!}+ \frac{2^k}{k!}\alpha k$$

$\implies$

$$4e^2  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!}+ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!}\alpha k$$

$\implies$

$$4e^2 - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!}\alpha k $$

$\implies$

$$3e^2 = 2\alpha \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} = 2\alpha \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^{k}}{k!}$$

Can you continue from here?